# comparing model A's fields values in model B's field django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have 100k records in both model 'A' and in model 'B'

Ex:

```
class A(models.Model):
    user_email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    user_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    book_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    payment_gateway_response = JSONField(blank=True, null=True)

class B(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(A, null=True, blank=True)
    pay_id = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    user_email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    user_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    total_payment = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=20, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to get B's objects using A's values

for example

```
all_a = A.objects.all()
for a in all_a:
   b = B.objects.filter(user_email=a.user_email, user_mobile=a.user_mobile)
```

This is fine, I am getting the results. But as it's 100k records it's taking too much time. for loop iteration is taking time. Is there any faster way to do this in django?

Comment: What are you actually using the loop for? What do you do with `b` when you get it?

Comment: its just for comparing the transactions. Nothing more

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of each value in a and filter b with those values.

```
a = A.objects.all()
emails = list(a.values_list('user_email', flat=True))
mobiles = list(a.values_list('user_mobile', flat=True))

b = B.objects.filter(user_email__in=emails, user_mobile__in=mobiles)
```

How ever results may have pair of email and mobile that are not pair in A. But if you make sure that emails and mobiles will be unique in A and the email and mobile in each B are based in one of the A' models, then you won't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in caching the A model, you may have a performance increase using `iterator()` (see for reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#iterator):

```
for a in A.objects.all().iterator():
    b = B.objects.filter(user_email=a.user_email, user_mobile=a.user_mobile)
```

Comment: That's still n+1 query, 100K + 1 in OP's case.

Comment: i need object a. Need to update it with some values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
import operator
from django.db.models import Q

q = A.objects.all().values('user_email', 'user_mobile')
B.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, [Q(**i) for i in q]))
```

If you want to do with some operations with every `b` object depends on `a`.This is not the way.